# domínio após o @ - HTML

Tags: html, validação

Alguém poderia me informar como faço para que o input só aceite um email com determinado domínio e rejeite outro ?

Ex:

```
gamboamurilo@gmail.com - ok
hillgnur@hotmail.com - erro
```

HTML

```
<input type="text" name="nome" class="txt_input first_input" placeholder="Nome" required>
                        <input type="email" name="email" class="txt_input" id="email" placeholder="E-mail" required>
                        <input type="email" name="confirmaEmail" class="txt_input" id="confirma-email" placeholder="Confirmar e-mail" required>
```

Comment: Resposta com jQuery vale?

Comment: vale sim :D toda ajuda é bem vinda

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Se for somente com `HTML`, você pode utilizar o [Pattern Attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input#attr-pattern) e validar com Regex, como no exemplo abaixo:

```html
<form name="myForm">
  <input type="email" name="email" pattern="[A-Za-z0-9._%+-]+@gmail.com" required="required" />
  <button type="submit">Enviar</button>
</form>
```

> Como lembrado pelo [@GustavoTinoco](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/146045/dom%C3%ADnio-ap%C3%B3s-o-html/146057?noredirect=1#comment301306_146057), o `pattern` não possui compatibilidade com o safari na versão Desktop. A lista completa dos browsers compatíveis (Desktop e Mobile) [pode ser vista aqui.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input#Browser_compatibility)

Comment: Randade, sugiro você colocar `*` antes do `@gmail`. Se ele já usa o `email`, ele vai validar isso automaticamente. Além do que, você está limitando o usuário, pois ele não poderia ter e-mails com `.`, `-` ou `_`.

Comment: @WallaceMaxters Editei a expressão. Não acho que com `*` seria a melhor opção, até porque essa seria uma segunda validação (a primeira é o `type="email"`). Mas realmente, você estava correto. Adicionei alguns caracteres na expressão. vlw

Comment: Randrade `%`? Essa me surpreendeu

Comment: no caso, sao emails empresariais sem o . ou -
usei o gmail como exemplo apenas

fora que, eu precisaria de mais de uma pattern, esse é outro problema que surgiu

Comment: @MuriloGambôa Basta alterar essa aprte `[A-Za-z0-9._%+-]` para `[A-Za-z0-9]`, assim aceitará somente letras e números.

Comment: Só fique atento que o pattern não é para todos os navegadores e não suporta no safari. Tive que recorrer a outro meio pois tem estas limitações.
http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_pattern.asp. Aqui pode ver testes http://www.wufoo.com/html5/#attributes

Comment: @GustavoTinoco Valeu por lembrar. Só esclarecendo, no Safari mobile é suportado. No desk que não é, como você mesmo disse. No link que eu coloquei na resposta fala isso, mas irei esclarecer mais. Obrigado pela ajuda.

Answer (score 3):

Você pode também fazer a validação usando a seguinte expressão regular no `Javascript`:

```js
var regex = /@gmail\.com$/;

var gmail = regex.test('wallacemaxters@gmail.com');

var hotmail = regex.test('wallacemaxters@hotmail.com');

document.writeln('wallacemaxters@gmail.com: ' + gmail);

document.writeln('<br/>');

document.writeln('wallacemaxters@hotmail.com: ' + hotmail);
```

A expressão `@gmail\.com` se encarrega de capturar a existência de `@gmail.com`, e `$` obriga que a expressão seja encontrada no final.